# Apache "header ALWAYS set" not returning Access-Control-Allow-Origin * header on 404

Tags: apache, cors, http-headers, http-status-code-404

In my (localhost, xammp) Apache httpd.cfg file I have `Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`. This works as expected when I HEAD or GET an **existing** resource, read, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` header **is** returned to the client. But if the resource does not exist, the 404 response does NOT have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` header set and thus the browser errors with CORS.

I understand that `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` (without "always") only returns the header for the 200-300 response range. I also seem to have understood that I need to add the "always" keyword to also have the header returned on any http response code other than 200-300. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work.

Are there any other magic phrases or keywords I need to add to REALLY always have apache return the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` header, regardless of the response code?

Answer (score 0):

What I see is that `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` Apache directive (without always) only works for 2XX statuses (ie successful ones).

To make it work on 30X and 40X statuses, the `always` keyword is needed.

That said, the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#Header) says that `always` does not overlap `onsuccess` (the default) in some cases. So you can perhaps try to use the following configuration :

```
Header onsuccess unset Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```